# How to check link is already clicked in java?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am new to Selenium and also new to java coding.
Can you please tell me coding for already selected or active link of table and print data of table for already selected link then go to next link automatically?

Comment: Does it have attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the following approach.

Algorithm  is simple: 
1) if a link has certain color attributed -> then it is supposed to be not clicked yet
2) otherwise ( if color attribute differs) -> it has been clicked

So you should find selector of the link to analyze:

```
String cssLink ="blalbalbla";
```

then you find this element (link):

```
WebElement link1 =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssLink));
```

then you get color attribute of it:

```
String colorExtracted= link1.getAttribute('color');
```

then you can analyze color obtained:

```
boolean result;
if(colorExtracted==clicked)  {
result = true;
}
else {
result=false;
}
```

Hope this idea helps you.